# Send generated file to client side to download in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to fetch data & generate a file then send the file to client to download. I am using a `StreamWriter` to write the file content & then I'm using Javascript to open a new window, but the file generated is not sent to the client side. The file is already saved in the path, only that the file is not exported to browser for download

```
protected void GenerateSummaryReport(int month, int year, string selmonth, string selYear)
{
    drpRepType.SelectedIndex = 1;
    string seconds = System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();

    DataTable dtAMName = CISEditor.Utility.Reports.GetAMNames(month, year);
    DataSet ds = CISEditor.Utility.Reports.GenerateSummaryReport(month, year);
        
    if (ds != null) 
    {
        if (ds.Tables["CIS"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string physicalPath = @:F:\Report\";
            string filePath = "SummaryReport " + selMonth + " " + selYear + "" + seconds + ".xls";

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

            if (fi.Exists)
            {
                fi.Delete();
            }

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(physicalPath + "\\Reports\\" + filePath);
            sw.Write(ExportToStringSummary(dtAMName, "FFFF6B, month , year));
            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();

            fi.Delete();
    
            StringBuilder strScripts= new StringBuilder();
            strScripts.Append("<script language=Javascript>");
            strScript.Append("window.open('" + physicalPath + "');");
            strScript.Append("</script>");

            RegisterClientScriptBlock("subscribescript", strScript.ToString());
        }   
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "No records found!";
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: is this [tag:webform] or [tag:asp.net-mvc]? oh, `RegisterClientScriptBlock` so webform.

Comment: @BagusTesa its webforms(aspx), yes yes correct

Comment: have you seen [this qa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27974766)? the key is to send a `Content-Type` and then push each bytes within the `Stream` through `Response.OutputStream`. alternatively, use `TransmitFile` if the file already written to disk.

Comment: your code seem to also give html page as response. did you want to invoke the "download" on a button press (postback)?

Comment: yes, i have used response before..but issue here is i need to reload page/redirect to same page after file is downloaded...using response will not work since it didnt accept subsequent actions

Comment: so you want show a page -> initiate download -> show thank you page? is that `GenerateSummaryReport` triggered by a postback?

Comment: show page (got generate button) -> show progress bar -> initiate download -> refresh the page/redirect to same page...yes triggered by postback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256621/discussion-between-suraya-zulkifli-and-bagus-tesa).

Comment: first of all, `window.open('" + physicalPath + "');` wont invoke the download. your client dont know the server's path, you have to use `Server.MapPath(physicalPath)` to get the correct url of the file assuming they sit within the website folder. regarding the progress bar, i think you will need a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814881).

Comment: also `<script language=Javascript>` is non-standard and deprecated (source [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)), use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead.

Comment: i see, but since i am testing it in my local, dont think Server.MapPath(physicalPath) will work..since the file is generated & save in my local ..for the progress bar, it is working..no issue on that one :)

Comment: This code does not compile. Copy‘Paste did not inject typos. Why are you posting code that does not compile? Even the syntax highlighter here tells you that this code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather easy to provide a download button for a file.

However, due to how the page life cycle works, you can have ONLY ONE page served back to the client side.

In other words, button + download file = easy.

button + download file AND THEN re-direct to another page? Nope! not really easy nor possible.

Same goes for downloading multiple files. In most cases, you have to zip up the files and then provide ONE download for the user.

So, say this simple grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridFiles" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Width="35%"
    CssClass="table table-hover" OnRowDataBound="GridFiles_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileDate" HeaderText="UpLoaded" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileSize" HeaderText="Size" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgPreview" runat="server" Height="80" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDownLoad"
                    runat="server" CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdDownLoad_Click"> 
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDelete"
                    runat="server" CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"> 
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In above, I have a button for download file, and the code for that is:

```
    protected void cmdDownLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton myBut = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)myBut.NamingContainer; // get current grid row

        string strFile = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
        string strFullFile = Server.MapPath($"~/UpLoadFiles/{strFile}");
        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFile);
        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFile);
        Response.TransmitFile(strFullFile);
        Response.End();

    }
```

And thus, the effect is this:

[image]

So, you can easy use a GridView, and provide a list of files to download.

Note the use of "transmitFile" to download the file.

However, as noted, you only get one file download, and it is quite difficult to have any other action(s) on the page occur, since you only in general allowed one "response" to the browser for a file download.

And for above, we don't have to use a file for the download, but you can send a byte array as the file.

Hence, we can with above "fake" a in memory file, and thus this:

```
        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFile);

        // pretend file is in memory
        byte[] FileData = File.ReadAllBytes(strFullFile);

        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFile);
        Response.BinaryWrite(FileData);
        Response.End();
```

Note that you need .net 4.5 or later to use the MineMapping.

And MineMapping does not require an actual file.

So, to get say the correct mine time for a .pdf file, you can do this:

```
string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("dummy.pdf");
```